# How to create a mailto link in windows forms application

Tags: .net, winforms, email

I want to know how to create something similar to a `mailto:` link (like on HTML pages) to a Windows Form.  So that on clicking it, the users default mail program should open a new blank email with the given email address in the `To:` field.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this is a .NET application then you can use a `LinkLabel` control. Just set the text property to the actual email address and then respond to the `LinkClicked` event handler like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" & LinkLabel1.Text);
```

You'll want to do some sanity checking on the email address and add some error trapping, but that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a LinkLabel control in Windows.Forms you can use.